# Using building functions with Postgres, Npgsql, and pgAdmin

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql, pgadmin

I am coming from an mssql world, and I can't seem to find documentation on some basic features for using the tooling around postgresql and C#:

1) In pgAdmin if I edit data via the edit grid, is there a way to use built in functions, like if I have a uuid column, in Mssql Studio I can enter NEWID() and it fills in the current date, but in pgAdmin a uuid_generate_v4() fails with 'invalid input syntax'.  A straight select uuid_generate_v4() works, so I know that the function it self returns values.

2) All of the npgsql examples that I can find show passing dates via the time on the local machine: "cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":datetimeParamName", DateTime.Now);"  Is there a way to pass now() in the parameter to force the DB to use its own date rather than the date of the machine making the call?

Thanks!

Comment: You should only ask one question in one question. On 2): Literally write `now()` in the query, instead of a parameter.

Comment: You probably cannot do that. Tools like pgAdmin are for viewing metadata, perhaps for viewing samples of the data, but certainly not for editing them.

Comment: The whole point of a parameter is to pass a value from the client to the database, you seem to want something else here. Why not just embed `NOW()` in your SQL rather than trying to use a parameter?

Comment: sticky bit had it right, new NpgsqlCommand("Insert Into Table (created,data) VALUES (now(),@data)");